# Upload in Flex without FileReference

Tags: java, apache-flex, flex3, filereference

Is there anyway of upload a file in flex 3.5 without using fileReference? Or even with fileReference, but without browsing, for example, I'm trying to take a printscreen and send it to my java web server
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a image snapshot and then use urlRequest to upload.  Have a look on http://marstonstudio.com/2007/10/19/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-flash-movie-and-automatically-upload-the-jpg-to-a-server-in-three-easy-steps/

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Create an upload service on the java side that takes a byte[] object as argument. On the client side, send a ByteArray. BlazeDS or the flex/jave bridge you use will convert the data for you